# Скорочення "Всього" та "у середньому"?

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни, скорочення

Підкажіть, будь ласка, як правильно скоротити назви у програмці для генерування звітів.

Є обмежене місце і повністю слова написати не виходить (англ. використовуються Sum, Avg).

Переглядав у словниках скорочень, таких слів не вдалося знайти.

Поки що, як варіант розглядаю таке:

> Всього - Всг.
>
> У середньому - Срд.
>
> У середньому годин - Срд.Год.

Але можливо є кращі варіанти.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Раџу використовувати технічні словники, де можливі такі слова. Наприклад [словник Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/language/Search?langID=799&Source=true&productid=0&searchTerm=*)ʼа перекладає так:

```
Avg | Сер. 
      Серед. 
      Срдн 
     (від середнє)
Sum | Сум
      Сума
```

Хоча, як видно, не дуже внормовано, однак маємо приклади.